# Why won't my PHP IF/ELSE statement work for determining the users operating system?

Tags: php, windows, if-statement, user-agent

I'm trying to create a page that will redirect users depending on their operating system. To begin with I need it to work redirecting Windows XP users to place A, other Windows users to place B and Mac users to place C.

I used this to determine Windows/Mac which worked fine:

```
<?php
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (strstr($useragent,'Win')) {
$os='<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh"
  CONTENT="1; URL=windows.php">';
} else {
$os='<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh"
  CONTENT="0; URL=mac.php">';
}

print "$os";
?>
```

Which worked fine, but then I tried to add a statement for Windows NT 5.1 (Windows XP)

```
<?php
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (strstr($useragent,'Windows NT 5.1')) {
$os='<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh"
  CONTENT="1; URL=windows-xp.php">';
} else if (strstr($useragent,'Win')) {
$os='<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh"
  CONTENT="1; URL=windows.php">';
} else {
$os='<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh"
  CONTENT="0; URL=mac.php">';
}

print "$os";
?>
```

I'm not convinced I'm doing this the best way, but any help thrown at me would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to know if it works or a different code to do the same?

Comment: Where does xp, win and mac-users get redirected?

Comment: First, relying on `User-Agent:` sniffing is a *bad* idea because it is unreliable and can be easily spoofed. Second, [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php).

Comment: Not all HTTP clients send a User-Agent header

Comment: I'm definately not a pro at this so things will be wrong. I know the second lot of code doesnt work - it doesnt redirect specific Windows XP users somewhere different to other Windows users.

Comment: Relying on the User-Agent may have some legitimate uses, even if it is generally a bad idea. For example, displaying screenshots from the correct operating system on some kind of help / manual page. Or positioning the download link for the most appropriate version of the software first. Just make sure this is only for eye-candy, and there is a sane default option.

Comment: Is there a better way of me doing what Im after then? Thanks for the replies so far

Comment: @Gruikya Got it in one, Should have said at the start that what I'm doing is displaying screenshots for a download guide but I also need to send Windows users to a different download than Mac users...

Answer (score 2):

Quoting my comment above:

Relying on the User-Agent may have some legitimate uses, even if it is generally a bad idea. For example, displaying screenshots from the correct operating system on some kind of help / manual page. Or positioning the download link for the most appropriate version of the software first. Just make sure this is only for eye-candy, and there is a sane default option.

For example, the WinXP-specific page should also include a link to the MacOS download, even if the Windows XP download is set in first place / most prominent. Also, the default version should also provide all download links, and should be fully operational. It can be, for example, equivalent to the page corresponding to the most-used version of your software.

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
switch ($browser->platform) {
case 'WinXP':
    // XP-specific
    break;
case 'WinVista':
    // Vista-specifict
    break;
case 'MacOSX':
    // OSX default
    break;
default:
    // Generic default
}
```

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php):

> In order for this to work, your browscap configuration setting in
>   php.ini must point to the correct location of the browscap.ini file on
>   your system.
>
> browscap.ini is not bundled with PHP, but you may find an up-to-date »
>   [php_browscap.ini](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp) file here.
>
> While browscap.ini contains information on many browsers, it relies on
>   user updates to keep the database current. The format of the file is
>   fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks Gruikya, just looking at implementing a test of this - will let you know how i get on!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through this array of user agents and matching operating systems and then redirect users according to result.

```
    $OSList = array(
    // Match user agent string with operating systems
    'Windows 3.11' => 'Win16',
    'Windows 95' => '(Windows 95)|(Win95)|(Windows_95)',
    'Windows 98' => '(Windows 98)|(Win98)',
    'Windows 2000' => '(Windows NT 5.0)|(Windows 2000)',
    'Windows XP' => '(Windows NT 5.1)|(Windows XP)',
    'Windows Server 2003' => '(Windows NT 5.2)',
    'Windows Vista' => '(Windows NT 6.0)',
    'Windows 7' => '(Windows NT 7.0)',
    'Windows NT 4.0' => '(Windows NT 4.0)|(WinNT4.0)|(WinNT)|(Windows NT)',
    'Windows ME' => 'Windows ME',
    'Search Bot'=>'(nuhk)|(Googlebot)|(Yammybot)|(Openbot)|(Slurp)|(MSNBot)|(Ask Jeeves/Teoma)|(ia_archiver)'
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, new to this (can you tell?) how would I then redirect them?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things, you're using `strstr()` when a simple `strpos` will do. I would stick it in a simple switch statement too so you can easily set a default/match multiple conditions.

Secondly, the proper way to redirect in PHP is to use the `header()` command like so:

```
header("Location: windows.php");
```

Put it all together, you get this:

```
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

switch(true) {
    
    // Windows XP
    case stripos($useragent, 'Windows NT 5') !== false: 
        header("Location: windowsxp.php");
        break;
    
    case stripos($useragent, 'Windows ') !== false: // Windows whatever
        header("Location: windows.php");
        break;
    
    case stripos($useragent, 'mac') !== false:
    default :
        // Default, maybe do nothing?
    
}
```

Read up on [PHP switch statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) and hopefully you will understand the layout. As others have said, relying on useragent isn't perfect, but for your simple download case it should be fine.